# MonoTouch library project only works when directly referenced

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I've created a simple library project to use in another monotouch project. When ProjectA References LibraryProjectB.csproj, it works perfectly. However when ProjectA references the .dll created by LibraryProjectB (LibraryProjectB.dll), I get a couple of compiler errors such as "Compiler Error, method *_*_ does not exist"

Why does directly linking the project work while the DLL that the project creates causes errors?

Answer (score 0):

This is because your build steps get out of order when you do this.  So you add a method to your library, and use it in your project.  Well, your app could get built first--and then not be able to reference the new method.

You need to reference the project directly.